# MediaPlayer cannot stop

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I put MediaPlayer into activity but after I close the app the voice does not stop

> This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final MediaPlayer audioBackground;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    audioBackground = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.spring);
    audioBackground.setLooping(true);
    audioBackground.setVolume(1,1);
    audioBackground.start();
```

> - I want when I get out of the app the sound stops
> - I've tried using release (); but the sound does not appear when the app is opened

Answer (score 0):

Override the onResume method:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){

    super.onResume();
    audioBackground.start();
}
```

and remove that line from the `onCreate` method.